# After deleting a button in Xamarin, the Compiler asks for "SyncContext.cs"

Tags: xamarin

H everbody,

if i launch my test app and delete a button from it, then debug and press a button on my app xamarin asks me to find "synccontext.cs", which i litereally never heard of. when i then press cancel the app crashes saying: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And later I get "Frame not in Module".

I dont really know what triggers that - all I did was delete a button. Has anyone ever seen anything likethis?

THanks!

Comment: You have an exception being thrown that may or may not actually be related to the .cs file you referenced. However if you simply debug your application you will be able to identify where the error is occurring and fix the code or account for the exception.

Comment: yeah thanks. I did that and I got it to work again - yet I really dont understand what causes this bizarre error ...

Comment: There are other stack overflow article in relations to that file, It seems to be one of those errors that presents itself as the problem even though it actually something else.